# Скачивание данных с финама в R (rusquant)

Tags: r

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при скачивании данных с Финама отраслевых тикеров (MICEXO&G, MICEXM&M) символ "&" распознается как выбор колонки, (Ошибка в [.data.frame`(fr, , (5:9)) : undefined columns selected(*)). Есть ли какой то способ на время отменить свойство этого символа?

```
library(rusquant)
date <- '2016-01-01'

getSymbols("MICEXM&M",from=date, src = "Finam")
Industry <- MICEXMM #Не скачивается и выдает ошибку(*)

getSymbols('MICEXFNL',from=date, src = "Finam")
Finance <- MICEXFNL #Все проходит идеально
```

Comment: `getSymbols('MICEXFNL',from=date, src = "Finam")` получается ошибка `Error in data.frame(names, res, markets) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 13754, 13756` (rusquant 0.4, R 3.3.1, WIndows)

Comment: @Ogurtsov У меня все скачивается, возможно проблема с установкой на Windows. 

`getSymbols('MICEXFNL',from=date, src = "Finam")`
`[1] "MICEXFNL"`
`Finance <- MICEXFNL #Все проходит идеально`

Comment: А если добавить '\' тоже не работает ? ( "MICEXM\&M")

Comment: @Batanichek, К сожалению, нет(
`> getSymbols('MICEXO\&G',from=date, src = "Finam")
Ошибка: '\&' -- нераспознаваемый префикс в строке в строке начинающейся с "'MICEXO\&"`

Answer (score 2):

Получается вот так

```
    > getSymbols.Finam(Symbols = 'MICEXM&M',  verbose = FALSE,  warnings = TRUE, auto.assign = TRUE, from = "2016-01-01") 
 Ошибка в `[.data.frame`(fr, , (5:9)) :undefined columns selected
> traceback()
7: stop("undefined columns selected")
6: `[.data.frame`(fr, , (5:9))
5: fr[, (5:9)]
4: as.matrix(fr[, (5:9)])
3: apply(as.matrix(fr[, (5:9)]), 2, as.numeric)
2: xts(apply(as.matrix(fr[, (5:9)]), 2, as.numeric),     as.Date(strptime(fr[, 
   3], "%Y%m%d")), src = "finam", updated = Sys.time())
1: getSymbols.Finam(Symbols = "MICEXM&M", verbose = FALSE, warnings = TRUE, 
   auto.assign = TRUE, from = "2016-01-01")
```

Включаем отладку

```
> getSymbols.Finam(Symbols = 'MICEXM&M',  verbose = TRUE,  warnings = TRUE, auto.assign = TRUE, from = "2016-01-01")
downloading  MICEXM&M .....

/table.csv?d=d&market=1&f=table&e=.csv&dtf=1&tmf=1&MSOR=0&sep=1&sep2=1&at=1&p=8&em=18886&df=1&mf=0&yf=2016&dt=18&mt=10&yt=2016&cn=MICEXM&Mпробую URL 'http://export.finam.ru/table.csv?d=d&market=1&f=table&e=.csv&dtf=1&tmf=1&MSOR=0&sep=1&sep2=1&at=1&p=8&em=18886&df=1&mf=0&yf=2016&dt=18&mt=10&yt=2016&cn=MICEXM&M&datf=1'
Content type 'finam/expotfile' length unknown
.......... .......
downloaded 17 KB

done.
Ошибка в `[.data.frame`(fr, , (5:9)) :undefined columns selected
```

Обращаясь по созданному url действительно получаем файл _без_наименований показателей (пустая первая строка) с 7 колонками

```
20160104,000000,3775.4600000,3780.5300000,3732.3100000,3732.9500000,1790746616
20160105,000000,3723.6200000,3793.4300000,3718.2100000,3793.4300000,2108887779
20160106,000000,3786.8100000,3829.9700000,3782.0200000,3818.0500000,3002195690
-----8<-----
```

"Больное место" это указание в конце url необязательного "cn=MICEXM&M"

По идее это должно "лечиться" указанием альяса для имени, поскольку есть строчка в коде getSymbols.Finam

```
Symbols.name <- getSymbolLookup()[[Symbols[[i]]]]$name
```

То есть предполагается что то такое:

```
 setSymbolLookup(QQQQ='yahoo',DIA='MySQL')
```

PS Если конечно я не запутался в логике использования псевдонимов. Их вполне логично выводить вместо оригиналов в качестве меток.... На худой конец просто выкинув это имя, в скачиваемом файле остаётся как имя индикатора индеферентное "table"